# Can I nest an array in a table?

Tags: tables, arrays

In my code I have this:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left.
\begin{array}{rcl}
    2x\lambda &=& 2 \\
    2y\lambda &=& 3 \\
    2z\lambda &=& 4 \\
    x^2+y^2+z^2 &=& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right\}
enter code here`\end{equation*}

$(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x} = &\lambda = \frac{3}{2y} \\
\frac{1}{x} = &\lambda = \frac{2}{z} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    y &= \frac{3}{2}x \\
    z &= 2x
\end{align*}
```

Which is using a lot of space in my document. So I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

[image: Nesting arrays]

I tried several ways but I only can do it without the brace. But the brace is necessary. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a collection of `array`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \left.
  \begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
      2x\lambda &= 2 \\
      2y\lambda &= 3 \\
      2z\lambda &= 4 \\
    x^2+y^2+z^2 &= 1
  \end{array}
  \right\}
  \rightarrow
  \begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
    \dfrac{1}{x} &= \lambda = \dfrac{3}{2y} \\[3\jot]
    \dfrac{1}{x} &= \lambda = \dfrac{2}{z}
  \end{array}
  \right\}
  \rightarrow
  \begin{array}{r@{}>{{}}l}
    y &= \tfrac{3}{2}x \\[3\jot]
    z &= 2x
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```